# Blinking Text and Sprites in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm back... After spending a lot of time working on my game I ran into 2 questions.  Both of them concerning displaying sprites and text.  The first one  is, blinking text.  I bet this has happened to many of you but by Googling it I could not find a direct answer to what is causing it.  If anyone could explain it to me why my text is blinking when I blit it to the screen I would greatly appreciate it.

My next question is almost the same as my first except it involves a sprite.  I added some code to the game that tells python to shoot a bullet from my player sprite when the space bar is pressed.  When I run it I get no errors and my bullet is displayed on my screen and then immediately disappears.  I am guessing these two bugs are directly related to each other but I am not certain to what is causing it.

Anyone out there who knows more about pygame than I do, could you please explain to me what is causing this so that I can determine a way to fix the problem.

Here is my bunker(the player) and the bullet class:

```
class Bunker(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
     pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
     bunker = pygame.image.load(bunk).convert_alpha()
     self.image = bunker
     self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
     bunker_x = 160
     bunker_y = 0
     self.firecountdown = 0
def update(self, milli):
     self.pos = self.rect
     if (self.firecountdown > 0):
          self.firecountdown -= milli      
def collide(self, EnemyTank):
     return pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.rect, EnemyTank.rect)
def fire(self, bullet):
     if (self.firecountdown <=0):
          bullet.x = 165
          bullet.y = 0
          bullet.fired = True
          bullet.speed = 100
          self.firecountdown = 500

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     def __init__(self):
          pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
          bullet = pygame.image.load(bull).convert_alpha()
          self.image = bullet
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
          self.x = 0
          self.y = 0
          self.speed = 0
          self.forwardx = 1
          self.forwardy = 0
          self.fired = False
     def update(self):
          self.pos = self.rect
          self.x += self.forwardx * self.speed
          self.y += self.forwardy * self.speed
          if self.x > 640:
               self.fired = False
```

and a section of my main loop:

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Courier', 76)
     text = font.render('Game Over', True, (0,0,0))

     if e_tank_x>640:
         screen.blit(text, (100,100))

     if bullet.fired == True:
          screen.blit(bullet.image, (bullet.x, bullet.y))
```

Comment: I think your bullet isn't disappearing so much as going off the screen very quickly. Try slowing it down a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid blinking make sure you have only one call to pygame.display.update or pygram.display.flip per frame. The call usually goes at the end of the main loop just before a clock.tick(fps) call.

Example:

```
# main loop
while true:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # process events and update game state

    # Draw current game state

    # Update display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Keep running at FPS frames/second
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem with Bullet, when you fire it, you set fire to true. Then, you set it to false after making the bullet. The problem is, it looks like you only draw the bullet while fire is true. This means that you draw the bullet for one frame, then set fire false and stop drawing it